# Duplicate value creation for arguments in Ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, coldfusion

I'm attempting to create a modal on a form that calls a CFC to update data and return results based off a combination of examples I've found on the internet and some research.  I've got it working more or less, but I'm running into a weird problem when defining my arguments where my passed values are entering my CFC function as a comma-delimited string duplicate of the value I pass.  My code looks something like this:

Javascript:

```
var amodal = $("##my-modal-form").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
          'Update Data': function() { $("##modal-form-test").submit(); },
          Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog('close'); aform.resetForm(); }
       }
    });

submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                target: '##client-script-return-data',
                data: {
                    fullname: $('##fullname').val(),
                    email: $('##email').val() 
                },
                success: function() { $('##my-modal-form').dialog('close'); successEvents('##client-script-return-msg'); }
            });
        }
```

ColdFusion:

```
<cffunction name="userModalTest" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="json">
    <cfargument name="fullname" type="any" required="true" default="" hint="unknown arg type" />
    <cfargument name="email" type="any" required="true" default="" hint="" />

    <cfset var testVar = '' />

    <cfset testVar = serializeJSON(arguments) />

    <cfreturn testVar />
</cffunction>
```

When I pass in my text string arguments and dump the struct, my fullname and email arguments are duplicated values, like "fullname: test,test" instead of "fullname: test".  I can make this stop by either not defining the data values in the submitHandler function or not defining the arguments in the CFC, but to my understanding neither of those solutions should actually work, so I don't quite understand what's happening.

Comment: Forgot to mention, using jQuery with the jQuery form plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are submitting the form no need to pass the `data` attribute to `ajaxSubmit()` call.

I think this is causing the ajax submit to submit an array of input params called `fullname` and `email`. That array is getting submitted as the coma separated string in the server.

Can you remove the `data` and try.

Ex:

```
jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
    target: '##client-script-return-data',
    success: function() { $('##my-modal-form').dialog('close'); successEvents('##client-script-return-msg'); }
});
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I'm looking at my code and comparing it to examples; the example I have that defines the arguments in the CFC doesn't actually use a form tag for the inputs and calls the CFC using a POST action instead.  Mine is using AjaxSubmit and defines the form with an action value.  I had tried your example previously and it did work, but I didn't understand why.  Thanks for clarifying.